# Объединение контуров в один на изображении

Tags: emgucv, компьютерное-зрение

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть бинарные изображения.

Как выделить одним прямоугольником область, где есть белые пиксели?

Если выделить контуры, то как все контуры объединить одним общим контуром?

Красным цветом - примерный результат.

```
Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat hier = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(imgopen, contours, hier, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.Tree, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxNone);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; ++i)
               { ... }
```

Спасибо.

[image]   
[image]   
[image]   
[image]

Comment: Так нужен прямоугольник или нет? На последней картинке непонятно, по какому принципу яма внизу и почему именно на такую высоту - может всё-таки выпуклой оболочкой заменить?

Comment: А как выпуклой оболочкой обвести сразу все контуры?

Comment: Ну она строится для множества точек, так что по идее контуры не важны: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/convex_hull_graham. Хотя, можно тем же алгоритмом, что для bounding box'а посчитать отдельно границы по каждой строке, тогда получится контур, натянутый на эту штуку по вертикали (но не выпуклый) - в принципе, можно ему подстричь впуклые углы и должно тоже получиться. А ещё вариант построить что-то ближе к тому, что на картинке - получить границы по обеим осям и выбрать точки, принадлежащие обеим. Впрочем, он снова распадётся, если можно порезать между фигурами горизонтальными/вертикальными линиями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насчёт этой библиотеки, но вообще bounding box считается элементарно и при желании даже распараллелить можно:

```
minx = width
maxx = 0
miny = height
maxy = 0

for each y
  for each x
    if color(x, y) == white
      minx = min(minx, x)
      maxx = max(maxx, x)
      miny = min(miny, y)
      maxy = max(maxy, y)

if minx <= maxx && miny <= maxy
  print(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
else
  print("Nothing found")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобралась. Получилось выделить прямоугольником область, где есть белые пиксели.